# inner join with DataTables

Tags: c#, winforms, datatable, devexpress, inner-join

I have two DataTables. I want to do inner join them into a new Data Table. There is no database access.

First columns of the Data Tables are key field.

```
 string ParentKeyColumn = dt1.Columns[0].ColumnName;
 string ChildKeyColumn = dt2.Columns[0].ColumnName;
```

Also I m using Devexpress components.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [this blog post on social.msdn](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/adodotnetdataproviders/thread/f122d7f4-3b7d-4d93-bd0f-8bb57cd990a4/).

Key details:

**Define a primary key:**

```
dt2.PrimaryKey = new DataColumn[] { dt2.Columns["Deptno"] };
```

**Define a data relation and add it to your dataset:**

```
DataRelation drel = new DataRelation("EquiJoin", dt2.Columns["Deptno"], dt1.Columns["Deptno"]);

ds.Relations.Add(drel);
```

Comment: Thanks James. But I dont have unique columns. Im getting error at this line;dt2.PrimaryKey = new DataColumn[] { dt2.Columns["Deptno"] };
: These columns don't currently have unique values.

Answer (score 0):

I would create the DataTable you require programatically and then load the data using LINQ as per the first of the following answers.

[Using LINQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/665754/inner-join-in-datatable-in-c-sharp)

[Using Merge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/285474/merge-2-datatables-and-store-in-a-new-one)

[From MSDN Forums](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/adodotnetdataproviders/thread/f122d7f4-3b7d-4d93-bd0f-8bb57cd990a4/)