# Join two data tables having common fields

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, datatable

I have 2 `datatable` objects (`dt1`,`dt2`), which have a common filed called "File_Name". I want to create a `datatable` (`dtFinal`), combining the two datatables to be used in gridview of asp.net

Each of the tables (`dt1`,`dt2`) can have overlapping column header names, meaning if dt1 has a header as "plant_code" `dt2` can also have the header as "plant_Code" but not mandatory.

My objective is to have a common datatable (`dtFinal`) with all the headers from all the individual datatables.

I tried something like this

```
  Dt1.PrimaryKey = New DataColumn() {Dt1.Columns(System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory & "\resources\files\" & "GRN" & ".csv")}
  Dt2.PrimaryKey = New DataColumn() {Dt1.Columns(System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory & "\resources\files\" & "Payment Data" & ".csv")}
  Dt1 = CsvToDataTable(System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory & "\resources\files\" & "GRN" & ".csv")
  Dt2 = CsvToDataTable(System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory & "\resources\files\" & "Payment Data" & ".csv")


  ds.Tables.Add(Dt1)
  ds.Tables.Add(Dt2)

  Dim drel As New DataRelation("EquiJoin", Dt2.Columns("File_Name"), Dt1.Columns("File_Name"))

  ds.Relations.Add(drel)

  Dim jt As New DataTable("Joinedtable")
  ds.Tables.Add(jt)
  For Each dr As DataRow In ds.Tables("Table1").Rows

      Dim parent As DataRow = dr.GetParentRow("EquiJoin")
      Dim current As DataRow = jt.NewRow()
      ' Just add all the columns' data in "dr" to the New table.

      For i As Integer = 0 To ds.Tables("Table1").Columns.Count - 1
          current(i) = dr(i)
      Next
      ' Add the column that is not present in the child, which is present in the parent.
      current("Dname") = parent("Dname")
      jt.Rows.Add(current)
  Next

  DtFinal = ds.Tables("Joinedtable")
```

Creating a `dataset` and a relation between dt1 and dt2 ...But this doesn't seem to work and giving me an error in line 1 `instance of object to be declared using New`.

Has someone tried something like this in Vb ? Or can my code be edited to make it work.

Further info: each datatable tb1 and tb2 have unique values in the File_Name column which is the first column. and hence can be selected as the primary key.

Comment: So you want to combine 2 tables into one if they have a matching value in the file_Name column?

Comment: no they would never have a matching value in the File_Name column.. this column is the only column that is mandatory and present in both the tables. so if we could join the 2 tables with File_Name as common column would all the headers in both the tables be present in the consolidated table ? if so then can my code be tweaked to do that ?

Comment: Ok, if DataTable 3 already has the file_Name it shouldn't add it right? or do you not care about duplicates

Comment: yes it shouldnt add it. and there should not be duplicates as well

Comment: You can enumerate all columns in `dt1` and add them to new table. And then, you can enumerate all columns in `dt2` and add them to new table. And then you can do `for each row-for each column` for both tables, to fill the data.

Comment: @T.S. thanks , can you provide an example for the same ?

Comment: Ok, I posted my working code now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you say, "Merge" it may mean one thing or another. For example, I may think of this method.

This is Working Code:

```
Public Sub  MergeTables()
    Dim t1 As New DataTable("T1")
    t1.Columns.Add("C1", GetType(String))
    t1.Columns.Add("C2", GetType(String))
    t1.Columns.Add("C3", GetType(String))

    Dim t2 As New DataTable("T2")
    t2.Columns.Add("C1", GetType(String)) 'same column
    t2.Columns.Add("C2", GetType(Integer)) ' same column, different data type
    t2.Columns.Add("C4", GetType(String)) ' different column

    Dim map As New Dictionary(Of String, String)

    Dim t3 As New DataTable("T4")
    MergeColumns(t3, t1, map)
    MergeColumns(t3, t2, map)

    Debug.WriteLine("Should be 5 columns and reality is: " & t3.Columns.Count)

    ' Add some data
    t1.Rows.Add({"data from t1 c1", "data from t1 c2", "data from t1 c3"})
    t2.Rows.Add({"data from t2 c1", 55, "data from t2 c3"})

    MergeRows(t3, t1, map)
    MergeRows(t3, t2, map)
    t3.AcceptChanges()


    For Each row As DataRow In t3.Rows
        Debug.WriteLine(String.Join(";", row.ItemArray.Select(Function(o) o.ToString()).ToArray()))
    Next

End Sub


Private Sub MergeColumns(totbl As DataTable, fromtbl As DataTable, map As Dictionary(Of String, String))
    For Each c As DataColumn In fromtbl.Columns
        If Not totbl.Columns.Contains(c.ColumnName) Then
            totbl.Columns.Add(c.ColumnName, c.DataType)
            map.Add(c.Table.TableName & "_" & c.ColumnName, c.ColumnName)
        ElseIf Not totbl.Columns(c.ColumnName).DataType.Equals(c.DataType) Then
            totbl.Columns.Add(c.Table.TableName & "_" & c.ColumnName, c.DataType)
            map.Add(c.Table.TableName & "_" & c.ColumnName, c.Table.TableName & "_" & c.ColumnName)
        Else
            map.Add(c.Table.TableName & "_" & c.ColumnName, c.ColumnName)
        End If
    Next
End Sub

Private Sub MergeRows(totbl As DataTable, fromtbl As DataTable, map As Dictionary(Of String, String))
    For Each row As DataRow In fromtbl.Rows
        Dim newRow As DataRow = totbl.NewRow()
        For Each c As DataColumn In fromtbl.Columns
            newRow(map(fromtbl.TableName & "_" & c.ColumnName)) = row(c.ColumnName)
        Next
        totbl.Rows.Add (newRow) 
    Next

End Sub
```

Result:

`data from t1 c1 ; data from t1 c2 ; data from t1 c3 ;    ;
 data from t2 c1 ;                 ;                 ; 55 ; data from t2 c3`

But may be, you need something else. However, this is good example how to do thing like this

Comment: Thanks for the reply, This is exactly wat was required. I will modify this code as per my requirements with minute tweaks. Thanks :)

Answer (score -1):

You could try the DataTable Merge.

```
dt3 = new DataTable();

dt3 .Merge(dtOne);
dt3 .Merge(dtTwo);
```

Look at this post for more info/solutions. [Merge 2 DataTables and store in a new one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/285474/merge-2-datatables-and-store-in-a-new-one)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: There ya go, added it .

Comment: @Dylan thanks, This seem to work if they have similar column names. But  in my situation its not the same. I tried the above but dt3 holds nothing . It cant merge dtOne and dtTwo.