# C# Join two DataTables

Tags: c#

I'm trying to join two datatables, both got the same amount of rows and just one column. Is there any fancy way in C# to do that? In result I need datatable with two columns where first row of first column is next to first row of second column.

Comment: So many answer on SO: Like: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20760681/linq-join-two-datatables or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/285474/merge-2-datatables-and-store-in-a-new-one

Comment: Can you show us what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to do this, so basically it's using the overload of `.Select` that provides an index of the current position within the iteration to lookup the corresponding row in `table2` that we're currently looking at in `table1`. We produce an object array with the two items in from each table for each row. Then we can just use `LoadDataRow` to put them into a destination table with two columns.

```
// create a target table with 2 columns
DataTable destinationTable = new DataTable();
destinationTable.Columns.Add("Col1");
destinationTable.Columns.Add("Col2");

// select all the rows from the first table, combined with the corresponding value for that row in the second table
var rowsCombined = table1
    .AsEnumerable()
    .Select((row, rowNumber) => new object[] { row[0], table2.Rows[rowNumber][0] });

foreach (var data in rowsCombined)
    destinationTable.LoadDataRow(data, true);
```

Answer (score 0):

From the [**ANSWER**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12284003/2445471) on this link by Tim Schmelter....

```
public static DataTable MergeAll(this IList<DataTable> tables, String   primaryKeyColumn)
{
    if (!tables.Any())
        throw new ArgumentException("Tables must not be empty", "tables");
    if(primaryKeyColumn != null)
        foreach(DataTable t in tables)
            if(!t.Columns.Contains(primaryKeyColumn))
                throw new ArgumentException("All tables must have the specified primarykey column " + primaryKeyColumn, "primaryKeyColumn");

    if(tables.Count == 1)
        return tables[0];

    DataTable table = new DataTable("TblUnion");
    table.BeginLoadData(); // Turns off notifications, index maintenance, and constraints while loading data
    foreach (DataTable t in tables)
    {
        table.Merge(t); // same as table.Merge(t, false, MissingSchemaAction.Add);
    }
    table.EndLoadData();

    if (primaryKeyColumn != null)
    {
        // since we might have no real primary keys defined, the rows now might have repeating fields
        // so now we're going to "join" these rows ...
        var pkGroups = table.AsEnumerable()
            .GroupBy(r => r[primaryKeyColumn]);
        var dupGroups = pkGroups.Where(g => g.Count() > 1);
        foreach (var grpDup in dupGroups)
        { 
            // use first row and modify it
            DataRow firstRow = grpDup.First();
            foreach (DataColumn c in table.Columns)
            {
                if (firstRow.IsNull(c))
                {
                    DataRow firstNotNullRow =  grpDup.Skip(1).FirstOrDefault(r => !r.IsNull(c));
                    if (firstNotNullRow != null)
                        firstRow[c] = firstNotNullRow[c];
                }
            }
            // remove all but first row
            var rowsToRemove = grpDup.Skip(1);
            foreach(DataRow rowToRemove in rowsToRemove)
                table.Rows.Remove(rowToRemove);
        }
    }

    return table;
}
```

You can call it in this way:

```
var tables = new[] { tblA, tblB, tblC };
DataTable TblUnion = tables.MergeAll("c1");
```

With some sample data:

```
var tblA = new DataTable();
tblA.Columns.Add("c1", typeof(int));
tblA.Columns.Add("c2", typeof(int));
tblA.Columns.Add("c3", typeof(string));
tblA.Columns.Add("c4", typeof(char));

var tblB = new DataTable();
tblB.Columns.Add("c1", typeof(int));
tblB.Columns.Add("c5", typeof(int));
tblB.Columns.Add("c6", typeof(string));
tblB.Columns.Add("c7", typeof(char));

var tblC = new DataTable();
tblC.Columns.Add("c1", typeof(int));
tblC.Columns.Add("c8", typeof(int));
tblC.Columns.Add("c9", typeof(string));
tblC.Columns.Add("c10", typeof(char));

tblA.Rows.Add(1, 8500, "abc", 'A');
tblA.Rows.Add(2, 950, "cde", 'B');
tblA.Rows.Add(3, 150, "efg", 'C');
tblA.Rows.Add(4, 850, "ghi", 'D');
tblA.Rows.Add(5, 50, "ijk", 'E');

tblB.Rows.Add(1, 7500, "klm", 'F');
tblB.Rows.Add(2, 900, "mno", 'G');
tblB.Rows.Add(3, 150, "opq", 'H');
tblB.Rows.Add(4, 850, "qrs", 'I');
tblB.Rows.Add(5, 50, "stu", 'J');

tblC.Rows.Add(1, 7500, "uvw", 'K');
tblC.Rows.Add(2, 900, "wxy", 'L');
tblC.Rows.Add(3, 150, "yza", 'M');
tblC.Rows.Add(4, 850, "ABC", 'N');
tblC.Rows.Add(5, 50, "CDE", 'O');
```

After the mergeAll call:

[image: after merge all]

Hope this helps...