# Merge two datatables with similar column in C#

Tags: c#, merge, datatable

I have two datatables(i don't have any database table, just simple datatable) as shown in screenshot (datatable1 and datatable2).

```
DataTable datatable1= new DataTable();
 new_Table.Columns.Add("Name");
 new_Table.Columns.Add("Number_A");
 new_Table.Columns.Add("Comment");
 new_Table.Columns.Add("ID");

DataTable datatable2= new DataTable();
 new_Table.Columns.Add("Name");
 new_Table.Columns.Add("Number_B");
 new_Table.Columns.Add("Age");
 new_Table.Columns.Add("City");
```

[image]

after binding them I want to compare two datatable and merge rows with similar "Name's column" value and  add other rows also as you see in screenshot, and create new datatable named result datatable...

Can you please explain to me how to achieve this?

Thanks

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datatable.merge?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: check this link for merge Datatable 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/285474/merge-2-datatables-and-store-in-a-new-one

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12284003/5985558

Comment: this method (data_table.merge) just return all dupplicate rows, i want to merge row with similar Name into one row and add other rows also to result datatable ...